# rare misspelled words messes my fastText/Word-Embedding Classfiers

Tags: python, gensim, sentiment-analysis, word-embedding

I'm currently trying to make a sentiment analysis on the IMDB review dataset as a part of homework assignment for my college, I'm required to firstly do some preprocessing e.g. : tokenization, stop words removal, stemming, lemmatization. then use different ways to convert this data to vectors to be classfied by different classfiers, Gensim FastText library was one of the required models to obtain word embeddings on the data I got from text pre-processing step.

the problem I faced with Gensim is that I firstly tried to train on my data using vectors of feature size (100,200,300) but yet they always fail at some point, I tried later to use many pre-trained Gensim data vectors, but none of them worked to find word embeddings for all of the words, they'd rather fail at some point with error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-644253c70aa3> in <module>()
----> 1 model.most_similar(some-rare-word)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py in word_vec(self, word, use_norm)
    450             return result
    451         else:
--> 452             raise KeyError("word '%s' not in vocabulary" % word)
    453 
    454     def get_vector(self, word):

KeyError: "word some-rare-word not in vocabulary"
```

the ones I've tried so far are :
conceptnet-numberbatch-17-06-300 : doesn't contain "glass"
word2vec-google-news-300 : ram insufficient in Google Colab
glove-twitter-200 : doesn't contain "5"
crawl-300d-2M : doesn't contain "waltons"
wiki-news-300d-1M : doesn't contain "waltons"
glove-wiki-gigaword-300 : doesn't contain "riget"

got their names from these sources, [here](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim-data#readme) and [here](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/english-vectors.html)

by inspecting the failing words, I found that even the largest libraries would usually fail because of the misspelled words that has no meaning like 'riget', 'waltons',...etc

Is their a way to classify and neglect this strange words before trying to inject them to Gensim and receiving this error ? or am I using Gensim very wrong and there's another way to use it ?

any snippet of code or some sort of lead on what to do would be appreciated

my code so far :

```
import gensim.downloader as api
model = api.load("glove-wiki-gigaword-300") # this can be any vector-library of the previously mentioned ones
train_word_embeddings = []
# train_lemm is a vector of size (number of examples, number of words remaining in example sentence i after removal of stop words and lemmatization to nouns)
# they're mainly 25000 example review sentence while the second dimension is of random value depending on number of words
for i in range (len(train_lemm)): 
  train_word_embeddings.append(model.wv[train_lemm[i]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you train your own word-vector model, then it will contain vectors for all the words you told it to learn. If a word that was in your training data doesn't appear to have a vector, it likely did not appear the required `min_count` number of times. (These models tend to *improve* if you discard rare words who few example usages may not be suitably-informative, so the default `min_words=5` is a good idea.)

It's often reasonable for downstream tasks, like feature engineering using the text & set of word-vectors, to simply ignore words with no vector. That is, if `some_rare_word in model.wv` is `False`, just don't try to use that word – & its missing vector – for anything. So you don't necessarily need to find, or train, a set of word-vectors with *every* word you need. Just elide, rather than worry-about, the rare missing words.

Separate observations:

- Stemming/lemmatization & stop-word removal aren't always worth the trouble, with all corpora/algorithms/goals. (And, stemming/lemmatization may wind up creating pseudowords that limit the model's interpretability & easy application to any texts that don't go through identical preprocessing.) So if those are required parts of laerning exercise, sure, get some experience using them. But don't assume they're necessarily helping, or worth the extra time/complexity, unless you verify that rigrously.
- FastText models will also be able to supply synthetic vectors for words that *aren't* known to the model, based on substrings. These are often pretty weak, but may better than nothing - especially when they give vectors for typos, or rare infelcted forms, similar to morphologically-related known words. (Since this deduced similarity, from many similarly-written tokens, provides some of the same value as stemming/lemmatization via a different path that *required* the original variations to all be present during initial training, you'd especially want to pay attention to whether FastText & stemming/lemmatization mix well for your goals.) Beware, though: for very-short unknown words – for which the model learned no reusable substring vectors – FastText may still return an error or all-zeros vector.
- FastText has a `supervised` classification mode, but it's not supported by Gensim. If you want to experiment with that, you'd need to use the Facebook FastText implementation. (You could still use a traditional, non-`supervised` FastText word vector model as a contributor of features for other possible representations.)

Comment: the first I did was was that I tried training the fastText model with my words but even that resulted in some words not being there too especially from test and validation sets as the trained model didn't see their words before, so I resorted to using pretrained model but with these I faced the problem I explained about misspelled words.

Comment: as for the lemmatization and stop words steps, well they were required in the assignment along with other pre-processing steps, I had no choice but to try different things, but yeah I noticed that during lemmatization process I had to choose between either nouns-verbs-adverbs which if I choose noun it might be the library I'm using for word embeddings only contain verb/adverb of the word or vice versa.

Comment: at last, Thanks for the detailed answer. ^_^, I think I might search for the pretrained words library by counting how many of training words exist in them then deciding to choose the one that contains the most.